# How do I access `OAuth consent screen` if my GSuite account was revoked?

Tags: google-api, google-workspace, google-developers-console

My old Gsuite account was revoked and I'm not able to access google developers console for the project created previously. If I create a new set of API key, client_id, client_secret with new google account, can I use google APIs with a new set of credentials but with an old set of user access keys( which is stored in my DB already)?
Or do I need to ask all my user's to re-authorize the app?

Is there a way to access google developer console for existing project somehow, either by using Gsuite admin or by creating revoked account again ?

Answer (score 1):

The client id, client secret, and any refresh tokens are linked to each other.  A user grants you access to the client id (Google project)

If you change the client id and client secret you are hooked to a new project your users will need to authenticate to this new application you will also need to go through any verification process again to verify this new application.

Comment: Can Gsuite admin access `Oauth consent screen` of my app?

Comment: Only the owner of the project on Google developer console can access it.   You need to login with the account that you used to create it or someone that you granted access to it.  If you used a gsuite domain account to create it then the gsuite admin could probably reset the password and log back in assuming they didnt just deleted your account. If they did just delete your account then its gone.

Comment: @DaImTo yes account is deleted but the  app is still live, is there a possibility to create same user again and have access to app ?